# WebRTC getDisplayMedia - How to avoid screen area selector

Tags: javascript, webrtc, screenshot

I would like to create a client-side screen capture of the actual webpage without a browser extension. Some bug reporting sites solved this problem so it seems to be possible. Browser compatibility is not an issue. It is ok if it works only on modern browsers.

I have tried html2canvas, but want a more accurate representation. So try to use WebRTC getDisplayMedia. I have tried [the WebRTC example](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/getdisplaymedia/).

It works, but the screen selector dialog has too much information. Screens, apps, tabs. Besides this, it doesn't reflect the actual site design.

In my case, I want always the actual browser screen where the user clicked the capture button.

Is there a way to preselect the current tab and eliminate the screen selector dialog?

Or maybe some other solution/technology?

Comment: You can't, this API doesn't expose useful deviceIds for the different sources (would expose too much info) and there isn't a "currentTab" displaySurface being defined.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. Then I have to look for another solution.